# usage of mean/meant for a shorter sentence

Tags: sentence-meaning

Can I write the shorter form of the first line as the second line ? Have they got the same meaning?

> Going to gym does not mean that it makes you healthy
>
> Going to gym is not meant to make you healthy

Comment: Not at all, the meanings are very different. The second one is: is not supposed to make you healthy.

Answer (score 1):

These two sentences are very different.
The first is awkwardly written but I *think* its intent is "Going to a gym does not make you healthy.". Or maybe "Just because you go to a gym doesn't mean you are healthy.".
That is, the first sentence warns the reader that it takes more than a gym to cause healthiness.

The second is grammatically fine but has a very different meaning. It claims that going to the gym has a different *goal* than health. Amanda_M's answer suggests that "everyone knows" the goal is health. But maybe you want to make a bold or somewhat controversial statement, such as this:
"Going to the gym is not meant to make you healthy. It's a performance. It's meant to make other people think you're healthy. I know people that go to a gym and never work out at all - they just strut around in Spandex and try to meet women."

(As an aside, for some reason it's common to say "go to *the* gym" even though there are clearly many gyms. People will even say "the gym" when referring to two different physical gyms on different days. It's very odd.)

Answer (score 0):

First sentence: 'does not mean' in other words just because you go to the gym doesnt mean you become more healthy. For instance you could talk the whole time you are there.

Second sentence: doesnt make much sense. The reason is that as everyone knows, going to the gym is (supposed to, intended to) make you healthy.